# Олимпиада по информатики задача "Наборы пирожных"

Tags: python, c++, олимпиада

**Задача 2: Наборы пирожных**

> На складе кондитерской фабрики хранятся пирожные двух видов —
> круассаны и эклеры. Круассанов A штук, а эклеров — B штук. Есть
> неограниченный запас подарочных коробок, в каждую коробку можно
> положить только три пирожных. При этом требуется, чтобы в коробке были
> пирожные обоих видов, то есть в одну коробку можно положить два
> круассана и один эклер или один круассан и два эклера.
>
> Определите, можно ли упаковать все имеющиеся пирожные в коробки и
> выведите подходящий способ размещения пирожных по коробкам.

**Входные данные**

```
Программа получает на вход два целых числа A и B, записанных в отдельных строках. 1 ≤ A ≤ 109, 1 ≤ B ≤ 109.
```

**Выходные данные**

> Если можно разложить все пирожные по коробкам в соответствии с
> условием задачи, программа должна вывести два целых числа. Первое
> число равно количеству коробок, в которых лежит два круассана и один
> эклер. Второе число равно количеству коробок, в которых лежит один
> круассан и два эклера.
>
> Если разложить все пирожные по коробкам нужным способом нельзя,
> программа должна вывести одно число −1.

**Система оценивания**

> Решение, правильно работающее только для случаев, когда числа A и B не
> превосходят 100, будет оцениваться в 60 баллов.

**Ввод**
4
5

**Вывод**
1 2

**Ввод**
5
3

**Вывод**

-1

Comment: Да откуда вас всех выпустили-то? Во-первых, "олимпиада по информатикЕ",  во-вторых, сами решайте свои задачи.

Comment: пора уже начинать давать заведомо неправильные решения похоже

народ вместо того, чтобы пытаться что-то сделать самостоятельно надеются на дядю,

если совсем туго с математикой 4 класса и 1 неделей занятий по программированию, то может да ну нафиг эту олимпиаду?

Comment: [поиск по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%9D%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((A+B)%3) return Не получится...

N = (2B-A)/3;
M = (2A-B)/3;
```

с проверками N >= 0, M >= 0.

Вроде бы так...

Ну, а код уж напишите сами - такой простой... :)

Comment: При A=5, B=1 ответ будет странноватым.

Comment: @Yaant Ну, добавить проверки.